# The meaning of という here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

ギュンター・メイによると、ロボットなどの機器に高速な無線リンクを追加することにより、高精度な連係やキャリブレーション（調整）が可能になり、大きな損害につながる故障や稼働停止の予測に役立つ**という**。さらに人工知能（AI）をはじめとする高度なソフトウェアを使うことで、機器の能力をさらに向上させることもできる。

This is the Japanese translation of the original WIRED English article: https://www.wired.com/story/factory-robots-may-point-way-5g-future/

Gunther May says adding high-speed wireless links to robots and other equipment allows them to be coordinated and calibrated more precisely, helps predict costly malfunctions and downtime, and allows sophisticated software, including artificial intelligence, to be piped in to make them more capable.

There are many uses of という so I don't know what this という refers to.

Thanks for reading my question.